# react-hook-form prefilled data for useFieldArray

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using `useFieldArray` in a child component. I'm fetching data from the database, then calling `reset(data)`. However, `useFieldArray`'s data doesn't refresh. See an example below:

```
const { control, reset, ... } = useForm({ ... });
const { append, remove, fields } = useFieldArray( {
    control: methods.control,
    name: 'employees'
});
const data = ...; // Retrieving data

useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        reset(data);
    }
}, [data]);
```

Everything works as it should, except for the data provided by useFieldArray. The data under `employee` hasn't been registered in react-hook-form, evident by the `DevTool`. If I print the data using `console.log(watch('employees'))`, I can see all the employees. They do not show in the DevTool, however, and `fields.length` is still 0. Only data I later append will show up in the DevTool and in `fields`.

I need a way to pre-fill the useFieldArray data, or at least notify it that data has been loaded and it should register it.